# Solution of Bessel equation with a parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

It is known that a zero-order Bessel equation can be written in the form:

$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dU}{dx}+\beta^2U=0$$

having solution:

$$U(x) = C_1 J_0(\beta x)+C_2 Y_0(\beta x)$$

where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are Bessel functions of first and second kind, respectively, and $C_1, C_2$ being constants.

Now, for the folowing equation, with a parameter $\alpha$:

$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2}+\frac{\alpha}{x}\frac{dU}{dx}+\beta^2U=0$$

How the solution $U(x)$ can be written?

Comment: Let $u(x)=x^a v(x)$. Substituting in, we see the differential equation for $v$ simplifies to the Bessel equation if we choose $a=(1-\alpha)/2$, but not the zeroth order Bessel equation.